# Multiple calls to a controller on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model that loads the Sidebar for my webpage, along with a Model that loads the main content. The content Model will be different for each page whilst the Sidebar model will remain constant. The content Model will change by the user clicking links:

```
~/Home/About
~/Home/Contact
```

What I ideally want to to put a line of code in _Layout.cshtml that loads a Controller that returns a PartialView displaying the Sidebar Model. So we might have:

```
<div id="sidebar">
   @Html.Render("~/SidebarController/GetSidebar");
</div>
<div id="content">
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

But I know this won't work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to use `@Html.Action("GetSidebar")` in the `_Layout.cshtml` file, then you can have an action in your controller

```
    public ActionResult GetSidebar()
    {
        //do stuff, populate menu items from database? etc

        // Pass the data to the partial view
        return PartialView("_Sidebar");
    }
```

You would need this in each of your controllers unless you put this in a base controller, which you can then inherit on all your other controllers and add `[ChildActionOnly]` to the top of your action so that it can not be called directly.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing you are trying to do. I use:

```
@Html.Action("GetSidebar", "SidebarController")
```

to draw my side bar and it works fine. I use ajax calls when changing views though so as to save on loading the sidebar over and over again and I have the ajax target the "content" div replacing its content with the partial view that represents each page.